# Task Scheduler - Batch script to run on condition that another task has completed

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

In Windows Server 2008 R2, I want to set up a Scheduled Task to run a batch script **on the following condition**

```
  -The task should only run once another task, that also runs a batch script, has   
   completed. How do I do that?
```

Note: Both task are set to run once daily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways that I see to do this:

1. From within the first task, if it successfully completes, then immediately schedule the second task from the command line.  Use `schtasks.exe /create /?` for syntax.
2. If you want the second task to run nearly immediately, `Call` the second task, when you detect the first task has completed.  If you want say, an hour to pass, use a 'wait.exe' type tool to temporarily pause the script, then execute after the time has passed.

Comment: Cool thank you. I see that you can also use the schtasks command to call a specific task - How do I get the ID or the Process ID of a task?

Comment: Mmm.  Do you mean of the task created by the Scheduled Task? it is a batch program.  Tasklist.exe - might get you to it.  Also, check wmic.exe.

Comment: There is another program called getpids.exe  http://www.scheibli.com/projects/getpids/ .  It will return the current PID, parent pids (one of which is your cmd.exe).  Youu would call it from your batch program and parse for Process ID.